# how is angularjs form.$invalid's value determined?

Tags: angularjs

I have inherited a form where the "do it" button is `ng-disabled` if `form.$invalid` is true.

How is `$invalid` determined?  I have seen setters in the documentation but they don't seem to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The [`$invalid`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$invalid) flag is set by the `FormController` if at least one containing control or form is invalid.

Comment: Right, but what is the definition of invalid?

Comment: Each [form control](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) can have a validator (i.e. required, type email/number, minlength...) and the control is invalid if it contains a value that doesn't match those validator rules. So if one containing control has `$valid = false` the form is invalid